# Azure function to SQL from a big JSON format

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to convert a JSON of 50K lines ( 4MB) into a SQL database.I am trying this approach in the code below but the function crashes before it finishes.I am not good at SQL so I do not know if there is any other approach I can follow for this purpose. I think is because of the big ammount of lines that take a lot of time for being executed.
The format of my dto is something like this:

> {"Data":[ {"name":"Variable
>   A","value":0.321721,"timecreated":"2018-1-15T11:10:7.977Z"},
>   {"name":"Variable
>   B","value":-8.932533,"timecreated":"2018-1-15T11:10:8.17Z"},
>   {"name":"Variable
>   C","value":-7.068326,"timecreated":"2018-1-15T11:10:8.58Z"},
>   {"name":"Variable
>   A","value":-3.580420,"timecreated":"2018-1-15T11:10:8.98Z"},
>
> ....50K lines
>
> {"name":"Variable
>   C","value":1.549976,"timecreated":"2018-1-15T11:10:7.977Z"},
>   {"name":"Variable
>   A","value":-8.701625,"timecreated":"2018-1-15T11:10:8.17Z"}]}

```
  public static async Task RunAsync([BlobTrigger("Container/Device/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
    {

        log.Info($"C# Blob trigger Entered\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        var sr = new StreamReader(myBlob);
        string strReadBlob = sr.ReadToEnd();
        var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object50KElement>(strReadBlob);
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
        {
            foreach (Variable v in dto)
            {
                //Send to SQL
                conn.Execute(XXXXXXX);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual error that you get?

Comment: Timeout. It seems it do not have enoguh time.

Comment: That seems most likely.

Comment: so I am trying to find an alternative to this code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SqlConnection is timing out as it's set by default to 30 seconds. So, you could increase the Timeout. But you might hit the 5 minutes Function Run limit. (if you use the Consumption Plan)

However, if you have 50k lines, it's probably better to use [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to stream data into DB, rather then insert each line individually. It's way faster and it will save you money. :)

You could use an example in the link above. Or you can use the following code if your json fields match DB columns:

```
public static int BulkInsert<T>(string connection, string tableName, IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;

        var reader = new EnumerableDataReader<T>(source);

        for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            var name = reader.GetName(i);
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(name, name);
        }
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
        return reader.RecordsAffected;
    }
}
```

You could "play" with the BatchSize to achieve a better performance or run the above function in a loop for every 1000 records.

Comment: I didnt try yet but is what i am looking for :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a SQLCommand object, as follows. N.B. The default Command Timeout is 30 seconds but you probably don't need this for each sql query so I have set it to 10. Play around with it if it still times out.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
{
  connection.Open();

  foreach (Variable v in dto)
  {
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(XXXXXXXXXX, connection);
         // Setting command timeout to 10 seconds
         command.CommandTimeout = 10;
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  } 
}
```

Comment: i think that the timeout is in azure function not in sql query

Comment: its not a matter of the error. I just think that is incorrect my approach